# My Visual Basic random joke and color generator doesn't work. Why is this?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, random

I'm making a program and I have a splash screen that I want to always generate one of the jokes I've made for it and one of the colors I've put there. I want it to generate them randomly, not so that a certain joke has a certain color, but so that they're both just completely random. Though when I start this program, it only shows a form with no text and the color I set it to in the designer.

I also have a label on the form called `lblJoke`.
The form is of course called `frmSplash`.

```
 Public Class frmSplash
  Dim rn As New Random
  Dim n As Integer
  Dim joke As String
  Dim daBBColor As System.Drawing.Color
  Dim daFFColor As System.Drawing.Color

Private Sub frmSplash_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblJoke.Text = joke
    Jokes()
    Colors()
    lblJoke.Text = joke
End Sub

Sub Colors()
    n = rn.Next(1, 4)
    Select Case n
        Case 1
            daBBColor = Color.Aquamarine
            daFFColor = Color.Black
        Case 2
            daBBColor = Color.Bisque
            daFFColor = Color.Black
        Case 3
            daBBColor = Color.DeepPink
            daFFColor = Color.White
        Case 4
            daBBColor = Color.Black
            daFFColor = Color.White
    End Select
End Sub

Sub Jokes()
    n = rn.Next(1, 5)
    Select Case n
        Case n = 1
            joke = "What do you call a pile of cats? - A meowntain."
        Case n = 2
            joke = "Why did Beethoven kill his chicken? - It kept saying 'Bach, Bach, Bach, Bach'."
        Case n = 3
            joke = "What do blondes and beer bottles have in common? - They're both empty from the neck up."
        Case n = 4
            joke = "Why couldn't the blonde add 10 and seven on a calculator? - She couldn't find the 10 key."
        Case n = 5
            joke = "What is the definition of diplomacy? - The ability to tell a person to go to hell in such a way that they look forward to the trip."
    End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: looks like an ideal situation to learn how to use the debugger.  set a breakpoint, step thru and compare what happens with what you expected to happen

Comment: fmtSplash is your form or is it a new class that you created? Because it seems like you have a "custom" class frmSplash and also a form class frmSplash.

Comment: @Eminem, the class is a automatically generated class. Visual Studio.

Comment: Keep Option Strict On at the top of your source code files for a while so you'll learn to avoid bugs like this.

Answer (score 1):

A meowntain eh? :)

First off, just a quick reminder that the Random.Next() function contains an *exclusive* upper bound, which means that your last joke and last color wouldn't get picked.

The sample below allows you to add as many jokes and color combinations as you like without having to modify Form_Load:

```
Public Class frmSplash
    Private jokes As String() = {
                                    "What do you call a pile of cats? - A meowntain.",
                                    "Why did Beethoven kill his chicken? - It kept saying 'Bach, Bach, Bach, Bach'.",
                                    "What do blondes and beer bottles have in common? - They're both empty from the neck up.",
                                    "Why couldn't the blonde add 10 and seven on a calculator? - She couldn't find the 10 key.",
                                    "What is the definition of diplomacy? - The ability to tell a person to go to hell in such a way that they look forward to the trip."
                                }

    Private colors As Color(,) = {
                                    {Color.Aquamarine, Color.Black},
                                    {Color.Bisque, Color.Black},
                                    {Color.DeepPink, Color.White},
                                    {Color.Black, Color.White}
                                 }

    Private Sub frmSplash_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim rn = New Random()
        With lblJoke
            Dim c = rn.Next(0, colors.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
            .BackColor = colors(c, 0)
            .ForeColor = colors(c, 1)

            .Text = jokes(rn.Next(0, jokes.Count))
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Colors method, you properly set the different colors to some variable. But no where do you set those variable to some controls. In the Load, you should do like the joke and set the value to a control.

In the Jokes method, you aren't doing cases properly. Remove the n =

```
Sub Jokes()
    n = rn.Next(1, 5)
    Select Case n
        Case 1
            joke = "What do you call a pile of cats? - A meowntain."
        Case 2
            joke = "Why did Beethoven kill his chicken? - It kept saying 'Bach, Bach, Bach, Bach'."
        Case 3
            joke = "What do blondes and beer bottles have in common? - They're both empty from the neck up."
        Case 4
            joke = "Why couldn't the blonde add 10 and seven on a calculator? - She couldn't find the 10 key."
        Case 5
            joke = "What is the definition of diplomacy? - The ability to tell a person to go to hell in such a way that they look forward to the trip."
    End Select
End Sub
```

I suggest you get out of the habit of putting all your variables out of your method. For example, "n" should be initialized inside your method and not as a class variable.